# What method is faster to get something from a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

What would be the fastest way to get the value from an object by key?

If You would have an object as such:

```
var obj = {
    title: 'A title',
    subject: 'A subject'
};
```

Would it be:

```
obj['title']
```

Or:

```
obj.title
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Easy way to find out...](http://jsperf.com/dot-vs-brackets123)

Comment: Verdict: `obj.title` is faster, but it's so infinitesimally insignificant that it's really not worth being picky over it.

Comment: Make this an answer, please.

Comment: @CaptainCarl you can't tell by that benchmark, it can lie and it can depend on a lot of other factors. That micro benchmark is cute and all, but it checks one scenario - what if the object has many properties? What if the code that runs it is JITed? What if it's not? What if dead code elimination is performed? The benchmark tells us very little here.

Answer (score 2):

There should be **no performance difference**. A smart JavaScript engine will determine `"title"` is a constant and convert the two to the same intermediate representation.

Also, note that you should not worry about performance differences at that scope. Knuth famously said that premature optimization is the root of all evil in 97% of all cases.

When you have a performance issue, then profile it, find the bottlenecks and change the relevant bits.

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance difference:

http://jsperf.com/get-value-from-object